# Wordpress (Cannot redeclare category_exists())

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, taxonomy

i started a tutorial on wordpress plugins and i came across this issue when i made a custom taxonomy:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNkUP.jpg)

The code is as follows:

main.php

```
//Exit if accessed directly
if(!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

/***********************************************/
/*                  includes                   */
/***********************************************/
include('includes/activate.php');
include('includes/enqueue.php');
include('includes/post_type.php');
include('includes/taxonomy.php');
/***********************************************/


/***********************************************/
/*                   Hooks                     */
/***********************************************/
//Checking wordpress version from includes/activate.php
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'jl_activate_plugin');
//enqueue backend styles & scripts from includes/enqueue.php
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'jl_admin_enqueue');
//Add nw job listings post type from includes/post_type.php
add_action('init', 'jl_register_post_type');
//Add new taxonomy from includes/taxonomy.php
add_action('init', 'jl_register_taxonomy', 0);
/***********************************************/
```

Creating custom taxonomy

taxonomy.php

```
function jl_register_taxonomy() {
    $labels = [
        'name'              => _x('Locations', 'taxonomy general name', 'location'),
        'singular_name'     => _x('Location', 'taxonomy singular name', 'location'),
        'search_items'      => __('Search Locations', 'location'),
        'all_items'         => __('All Locations', 'location'),
        'parent_item'       => __('Parent Location', 'location' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Location:', 'location' ),
        'edit_item'         => __('Edit Location', 'location'),
        'update_item'       => __('Update Location', 'location'),
        'add_new_item'      => __('Add New Location', 'location'),
        'new_item_name'     => __('New Location Name', 'location'),
        'menu_name'         => __('Locations', 'location'),
    ];

    $args = [
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => ['slug' => 'location'],
    ];
    register_taxonomy('location', ['job'], $args);
}
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Looks as though you are requiring `/admin/taxonomy.php` again somewhere; it's not clear from your code how you are achieving that though.

Comment: i just include the file above in my main php file with:
include('includes/taxonomy.php');

Comment: I edited my code above to make things a little more clear.

Comment: Why are you requiring core WordPress files? They are loaded without you needing to worry about them.

Comment: What do you mean by core files?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error. I copied the taxonomy code and pasted it on my custom post type php file. For some reason it worked.